# How to draw sprites using DMA2D with transparency using stm32?

Tags: stm32, graphics

I am using STM32F429I-Discovery board I want to draw sprites on TFT-LCD with transparency on top of background image , I used black color as the transparent color for the images that I want to draw and used DMA2D at blending mode but the black color is not transparent and the sprite was drawn with a black color surrounding it.

the sprite color mode is RGB565 (I have tried ARGB888 also with no hope) .

The code:

```
void DrawSprite(uint32_t img , uint32_t SprNo , uint32_t w , uint32_t h  , int format){

/* Configure the DMA2D Mode, Color Mode and output offset */

  Dma2dHandle.Instance          = DMA2D;
  Dma2dHandle.Init.ColorMode    = DMA2D_RGB565;
  Dma2dHandle.Init.OutputOffset = 240 - w ;

  /* Foreground Configuration */
  Dma2dHandle.LayerCfg[1].AlphaMode = DMA2D_NO_MODIF_ALPHA;
  Dma2dHandle.LayerCfg[1].InputAlpha = 0xFF;
  Dma2dHandle.LayerCfg[1].InputColorMode = format;
  Dma2dHandle.LayerCfg[1].InputOffset = 0;



  if(SprNo == BACKGROUND)
  {
      Dma2dHandle.Init.Mode = DMA2D_M2M ;
  }
  else
  {
      Dma2dHandle.Init.Mode = DMA2D_M2M_BLEND ;

      /* Foreground Configuration */
      Dma2dHandle.LayerCfg[0].AlphaMode = DMA2D_NO_MODIF_ALPHA;
      Dma2dHandle.LayerCfg[0].InputAlpha = 0xFF;
      Dma2dHandle.LayerCfg[0].InputColorMode = DMA2D_INPUT_RGB565;
      Dma2dHandle.LayerCfg[0].InputOffset = Dma2dHandle.Init.OutputOffset;

      /* Configure DMA2D Stream source2 address */
      WRITE_REG(Dma2dHandle.Instance->BGMAR, (uint32_t)RenderBuffer);
  }


  /* DMA2D Initialization */
  HAL_DMA2D_Init(&Dma2dHandle);

  HAL_DMA2D_ConfigLayer(&Dma2dHandle, 1);
  if(SprNo != BACKGROUND)
         HAL_DMA2D_ConfigLayer(&Dma2dHandle, 0);

  /*DMA2D Transfer Start*/
  HAL_DMA2D_Start(&Dma2dHandle,(uint32_t) img, (uint32_t)RenderBuffer, w, h );
  HAL_DMA2D_PollForTransfer(&Dma2dHandle, 100);}
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a pure programming problem.  Are you certain you're on the right stack?  We do have engineers who program here, and perhaps they're more familiar with STM32, but nonetheless, you might be better off with a pure programming stack.

Comment: My question have many details about specific hardware peripherals in STM32F429 LTDC , DMA2D and not pure programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the pixel formats you've used so far (RGB565 and RGB888) have Alpha values, so the DMA2D will not treat any of them as transparent. A pixel value of 0 is black, not transparent, so black is what you see.
If you want individual pixels to be transparent when you're manipulating them with the DMA2D 'ChromeArt' accelerator then you need to use a pixel format which includes an *Alpha* value like ARGB1555, ARGB8888, etc - and set the Alpha value to 0 for the pixels which you want to be transparent.

Your other option is to use the 'Color Keying' feature of the LTDC Display controller - this does not require your pixel format to have an Alpha value, but does require that you use 2 framebuffers in RAM - one for the foreground layer (where you'll place your sprite(s) and another for the background layer.
To do this you would choose a particular color value as the transparent pixel value, and configure the LTDC_L1CKCR (Foreground Layer Color Keying)  register for that color.
Then when the LTDC module builds the 'final' image by merging the foreground layer onto the background layer it'll ignore all foreground pixels with that color and show the background pixels instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. I tried your second option (color keying) and it's working :) ... the background is fixed so I don't use buffer for it I just use a pointer to bitmap stored in flash and I used only a buffer for the foreground layer..

Comment: But I still have problem about DMA2D .. should both layers [ Background + Foreground ] use alpha value for it say ARGB1555 or only foreground layer?
Should the output color format also have alpha channel or I can use RGB565?

Comment: If you're using option 2 (color keying) then you don't need a pixel format with alpha - you can continue using RGB565. If you want to use alpha values with the DMA2D, then you can individually configure the DMA2D layers as you need - so you can have one with a pixel format with alpha and the other with a pixel format without alpha.

Comment: Something else you need to remember when using the DMA2d which confused me when I first started working with it: the 2 DMA2D 'layers' are completely different entities to the LTDC background and foreground layers. I prefer to think of the DMA2D 'layers' as simply the input buffers (which night be whole frames or smaller sprite blocks or whatever) and then the DMA2D *output* gets directed to either of the LTDC's background or foreground layer frame buffers.